# Spring boot service in kubernetes always responses with HTTP status 400

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-security

We have Spring Boot service running in Kubernetes.
This service has endpoint:
- GET /healthz

We have liveness probe that uses this endpoint. Probe runs successfully.
It means that the endpoint is reachable from the service pod (localhost).

When I run in the service pod :
    `wget https://localhost:8080/healthz`
I get an answer (OK)

When I try to call this endpoint outside the pod `wget https://myhost:8080/healthz`, I get **response 400 without body**.
I don't see any logs of Sprint. It seems that it does not reach the Sprint .
When I added flag `-Djavax.net.debug=all` I see in log that TLS handshake finished and then:

```
GET /healthz HTTP/1.1    
host: myhost:8080    
accept: application/json    
Connection: close
```

and immediately

```
HTTP/1.1 400 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 25 Jun 201 8 08:43:43 GMT
Connection: close
```

When I try `wget https://myhost:8080/blahblah` (non existing endpoint),
I still get 400, not 404!

When I try `wget https://myWronghost:8080/healthz` (wrong host), I get an error `Bad address`. It means that host 'myhost' is correct (otherwise I would get this error).

Docker file:

> FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
>     VOLUME /tmp
>     ARG JAR_FILE
>     COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
>     ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
>     ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djavax.net.debug=all", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
>     EXPOSE 8080

Summing up:
The service endpoints are accessible from within service pod, but not accessible from outside the pod.
Any idea why?

Update:
The problem was solved by calling the service with **fully qualified domain name** : *serviceName.namespaceName.svc.cluster.local*
Tomcat didn't accept calls with short domain *serviceName.namespaceName*, it responded 400.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue can be caused by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13205.
All you have to do is upgrade Tomcat version to 8.5.32. You can do that by adding the version in pom.xml file.

```
 <properties>
    <!-- your properties -->
    <tomcat.version>8.5.32</tomcat.version>
 </properties>
```

Comment: We use Spring 2.0.2.RELEASE and Tomcat is embedded in it, so we don't specify its version.

Comment: The property I have added is optional and can override the version of embedded Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring boot 2 this may be due to **bug in Tomcat 8.5.31** that doesnt allow '-' in last part of FQDN

**Update Tomcat to 8.5.32** fixes this.

Reference:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13205
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62383
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62371

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it has any influence here, but you're trying everything with `https`. Can you try with `http` instead? Your spring app probably doesn't support https on port 8080.

Comment: yes, we are using port 8080 and recently added tls support, so it's `https`. The same problem with `http` too

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by calling the service with fully qualified domain name :
**service-name.namespace-name.svc.cluster.local**
The service didn't accept calls with **service-name.namespace-name**, responded 400.